# Jar Shading With Dynamically Loaded Classes With Maven

Tags: java, maven, classloader, geotools, maven-shade-plugin

I am using the maven plugin to shade and minimize a jar before I upload it to AWS lambda.  However, I'm getting a runtime exception because of a missing class.  As far as I know, this is due to some 'dynamic' class loading or something, but I'm not sure if A) there is a solution or B) what it might be, beyond efforts I've already made.  I read some good [articles][1] on jar shading and I think I understand the general idea, but I can't find an example of my particular problem documented anywhere.

```
[INFO] Replacing original artifact with shaded artifact.
[INFO] Replacing /home/ro007848/Workspace/geometry-service/target/geometry-service-1.0.0.jar with /home/ro007848/Workspace/geometry-service/target/geometry-service-1.0.0-shaded.jar
```

Below is the stack trace I see in cloudwatch:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find function Length
at org.geotools.filter.FunctionFinder.findFunction(FunctionFinder.java:208)
at org.geotools.filter.FunctionFinder.findFunction(FunctionFinder.java:152)
at org.geotools.filter.FunctionFinder.findFunction(FunctionFinder.java:129)
at org.geotools.filter.FilterFactoryImpl.function(FilterFactoryImpl.java:819)
at org.geotools.feature.FeatureTypes.createLengthRestriction(FeatureTypes.java:148)
```

Here are the contents of my pom file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                <filters>
                    <filter>....</filter>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>org.geotools:*</artifact>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </filter>
..........
                    <filter>....</filter>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>com.amazonaws:*</artifact>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**</include>
                        </includes>
                    </filter>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I take the jar that gets generated, unzip, and look inside,

```
➜  geotools git:(dev-S62039_geojson-to-shapefile_ro007848) ✗ pwd                                                                                                                                                                              
/home/ro007848/Workspace/geometry-service/target/jar-shaded-simple/jar-contents/org/geotools                                                                                                                                                  
➜  geotools git:(dev-S62039_geojson-to-shapefile_ro007848) ✗ grep -r "Length"
```

this is what I find:

```
................
Binary file ows/wms/CRSEnvelope.class matches
Binary file filter/FilterSAXParser.class matches
Binary file filter/FilterDOMParser.class matches
Binary file filter/LengthFunction.class matches
Binary file filter/function/StaticGeometry.class matches
Binary file filter/function/FilterFunction_strLength.class matches
Binary file filter/function/FilterFunction_strToLowerCase.class matches
Binary file filter/function/FilterFunction_strToUpperCase.class matches
Binary file filter/function/FilterFunction_geomLength.class matches
Binary file filter/ExpressionDOMParser.class matches
Binary file referencing/util/CRSUtilities.class matches
Binary file referencing/crs/DefaultProjectedCRS.class matches
................
```

It appears as though there is a "Length" function there...  If my exception isn't talking about this one, which one is it talking about?  How do I being debugging this issue?  Is there a 'scorched-earth' approach to setting `<include>` filters in jar-shading plugin configuration so get this working?

Someone else suggested I try adding these classes explicitly in the shading configuration, like so:

```
<filter>
    <artifact>org.geotools:gt-main</artifact>
    <includes>
        <include>org/geotools/filter/LengthFunction.class</include>
    </includes>
</filter>
```

but that either doesn't work, or I'm not doing it right.

More info:

When I run integration tests for this code locally, there is no problem with execution.  Whatever functions are needed are found.  However, when I execute the same integration tests against my resources deployed in AWS (this one lambda backed by this one jar), *that's* when I get the failure.  I find it difficult to uncover much in the debugger about what exactly I need to include because the code appears to do things 'dynamically' and I'm having trouble following it closely.

I'm at my wits end!

EDIT:
I took a look at the e-mail thread posted by @gerold-broser, but I'm not sure it is applicable because according to `mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose` I am on version 25.1 of geotools. The output says stuff like

````
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>  <!-- com.digitalglobe.p2020.common:common-dependencies:3.47.139813, line 922 -->
        <artifactId>gt-coverage</artifactId>  <!-- com.digitalglobe.p2020.common:common-dependencies:3.47.139813, line 923 -->
        <version>25.1</version>  <!-- com.digitalglobe.p2020.common:common-dependencies:3.47.139813, line 924 -->
      </dependency>
    ``` and 
    ```
        <dg-geotools.version>25.1</dg-geotools.version>  <!-- com.digitalglobe.p2020.common:common-dependencies:3.47.139813, line 218 -->
    ```


  [1]: https://medium.com/@akhaku/java-class-shadowing-and-shading-9439b0eacb13
````

Comment: Have you seen [this thread on GeoTools' mailing list](https://sourceforge.net/p/geotools/mailman/geotools-gt2-users/thread/AANLkTi%3Dbdh5vtNePYhRMbQjH36aA9_YuRg8KMMXko5w8%40mail.gmail.com/#msg27225816)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As is discussed in the [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) [FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/faq.html#how-do-i-create-an-executable-jar-for-my-geotools-app) GeoTools relies on `META-INF/services` files from each of the GeoTools modules used by your application. Unless you specifically instruct the `Shade` plugin to merge these files then you will end up with the first or last one the maven sees (i forget which).

So add this to your pom's `build` section:

```
       <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.3.1</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>shade</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                      <transformers>
                          <!-- This bit merges the various GeoTools META-INF/services files         -->
                          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
                      </transformers>
                  </configuration>
              </execution>
          </executions>
      </plugin>
```

If you want to check it's worked then you need to check that `META-INF/services/org.opengis.filter.expression.Function` includes `org.geotools.filter.LengthFunction`

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect.  It did not occur to me to check out the GeoTools FAQ.  Perhaps you could add my issue to a "common issues" page linking to the FAQ.  Then, I would have possibly found the FAQ myself while Googling for other instances of the same problem as I had.

Comment: Just a curiosity. adding the transformers is enough for shade-plugin to find the dynamic classes, or it is still necessary to have the filters in order to not have the dynamic classes removed from final jar ?